# System Threading: Cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

The error I'm having from my thread is:

Cross-thread operation not valid. Control 'richTextBox8' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

I have this code I use for my List of string that is causing the error.

```
string[] parts = richTextBox8.Text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Now I'm working with using System.Threading that requires to transform the code above into a format something like this code to work but I'm unable to do it or is there some other way?

```
richTextBox8.Invoke((Action)(() => richTextBox8.Text += "http://elibrary.judiciary.gov.ph/" + str + "\n"));
```

Comment: Your second code sample (or something very much like it) is what you need. What problem are you getting with the second code?

Comment: What typeof is your textbox ? I've read that some 3rd Party vendors have problems in this scenario

Comment: Ideally, you should grab `richTextBox8.Text` before you start the threaded operation - could you give us more context please?

Comment: Hi. The second code is working properly. I just want to know how to format the first code just like the second code.

Comment: `richTextBox8.Invoke((Action)(() => { /*do whatever you want */}));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] parts = null;
richTextBox8.Invoke((Action)(() => 
    {
        parts = richTextBox8.Text.Split(new string[] { " " },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); //added semicolon
    }));
```

Answer (score 2):

your string array (string[]) looks fine to me. If there are whitespaces inisde richTextBox8 it  should do the splitting.

Regarding your Threading, try with a use of delegate, like:

```
    public delegate void MyDelegate(string message);

   //when you have to use Invoke method, call this one:
   private void UpdatingRTB(string str)
   {
       if(richTextBox8.InvokeRequired)
           richTextBox8.Invoke(new MyDelegate(UpdatingRTB), new object []{ msg });
       else
           richTextBox8.AppendText(msg);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need the text extraction done on the UI thread.

With [variable capturing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt/archive/2008/03/01/understanding-variable-capturing-in-c.aspx):

```
string text = null;
richTextBox8.Invoke((Action)(() => text = richTextBox8.Text));
string[] parts = text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Without variable capturing (slightly more efficient):

```
var ret = (string)richTextBox8.Invoke((Func<string>)(() => richTextBox8.Text));
parts = ret.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: You're welcome. Note that this is slightly more efficient than the answer you selected, because you don't do the splitting on the UI thread (as a rule, you want to stay out of the UI thread as much as you can)